# Remove repeating column values during an Inner Join Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have two tables

Table-1

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName
    1            A
```

Table-2

```
EmployeeId  Month
    1        Jan
    1        Feb
    1        Mar
    1        Apr
```

When I apply inner join based on employeeid I will get result like this

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName    Month
    1            A           Jan
    1            A           Feb
    1            A           Mar
    1            A           Apr
```

I want to remove all the repeating column values from Table-1. My result should be like this.

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName    Month
    1            A           Jan
                             Feb
                             Mar
                             Apr
```

Please suggest any ideas on this.

Comment: So you want to replace the actual value with `NULL`?

Comment: replace actual value with either Null or empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT t1.EmployeeId AS t1EmployeeID, t1.EmployeeName,
         t2.EmployeeId AS t2EmployeeID, Month,
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY t1.EmployeeId 
                                 ORDER BY MONTH(t2.Month + ' 1 2015'))
  FROM Table2 t2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t1
  ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
)
SELECT EmployeeId = CASE WHEN RN = 1 
                    THEN t1EmployeeID ELSE NULL END,
       EmployeeName = CASE WHEN RN = 1 
                    THEN EmployeeName ELSE NULL END, 
       Month
FROM CTE
```

The tricky part was the ordering by int-month from abbreviated month name.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81e53/5/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thank a ton Tim Schmeleter. It reduces lot of my effort.